# Run generator when button is clicked

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create a Button to generate a password with `tkinter` but when the script is running, the password is already generated and the button doesn't work.

Here is the button script:

```
import tkinter as tk
import string
from random import randint, choice

def generate(target):
    letter_min = 6
    letter_max = 15
    all_chr = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation + string.digits
    password = "".join(choice(all_chr)for x in range(randint(letter_min, letter_max)))
    target.delete(0, tk.END)
    target.insert(0, password)

password_button = tk.Button(f2, text="Générer", font=("Arial", 20), bg=gris, fg='white', command=generate(password_entry))
password_button.pack(fill=tk.X)
```

Comment: Replace `generate(password_entry)` with `lambda : generate(password_entry)`. `command` takes a function as a parameter, not the value returned by a function.

Answer (score 1):

```
password_button = tk.Button(f2, text="Générer", font=("Arial", 20), bg=gris, fg='white', command=generate(password_entry))
```

The `command` argument of `tkinter.Button`'s constructor takes a `function`, not the value returned by the function.

---

Replace

```
command=generate(password_entry)
```

with

```
command=lambda : generate(password_entry)
```